# Why is IIS/ASP.Net/MVC3 setting the max-age to 7200?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.Net MVC 3 web application that I am using to deliver files (in this specific test, pdf files). The files won't ever change (if the file changes, a new URL is generated). So I would like to set the max-age (for Cache-Control), to 31536000 (1 year).

Code...

```
Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
```

Fiddler response...

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=7200
```

However, if I set the max-age to less than 7200, it works just fine...

Code...

```
Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7199));
```

Fiddler response...

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=7199
```

I've tried setting the [OutputCache] attribute on the action as well with the same results.

Any idea where the 7200 is coming from and how to allow it to be more than that?

Comment: Good question. Is this occurring locally or on a server? IIS Version? Integrated Mode?

Comment: It's IIS7, integrated mode, on a Win8 64 bit dev machine.

Comment: Are the pdfs is a specific folder?  Does the web.config have any cacheControlMaxAge values set?

Comment: I did not see cacheControlMaxAge values in the web.config in the vdir, the parent, or applicationHost.config. The pdfs are actually generated, so they aren't in any particular folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior suggests the max-age value is being set somewhere previously in the application. According to the [SetMaxAge documentation in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setmaxage.aspx):

*If the SetMaxAge method is called repeatedly, on the second and subsequent calls, the value of the maximum age can only be decreased.*

If there is code setting max-age to 7200 earlier in the pipeline, all you can do is set it to a lower number. Trying to set it to a higher number will not work.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up why it was only allowing it to be lowered. I wonder why they don't allow the value to be increased. I was able to quickly find where it was getting set to 2 hours (7200) once that mystery was resolved. It was set in the global.asax.cs file in Application_EndRequest.